# ASP.NET trigger update panel by _dopostback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an FormView inside updatepanel, they are wrapped in modal dialog(bootstrap).

When user click on "Edit" button, but then decide to close the diaglog, I need to switch the formview from "editing" mode to "readonly" mode by doing a postback. 
  So I use javascript to listen to modal close event, and call:

```
javascript: __doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$ClientInfoFormView$CancelBtn", "");
```

well, it did trigger asyncpostback.

However, the page freezes, all UI is not clickable anymore!

note that if I manually click the "cancel" button of the formview, it does the async postback and enter readonly mode with no problem.

I used firebugs to see the postback data and returned partial page, they looked the same!
I've been battling this problem for 2 days with no clue.
I don't see any logical difference between clicking the "cancel" button (which does the same `_dopostback` call) and calling `_dopostback` by my javascript.

please help.!
Thanks

Comment: perhaps using e.preventDefault in the JS onclick portion will help.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
__doPostBack("ctl00$MainContent$ClientInfoFormView$CancelBtn", "");"
```

try

```
document.getElementById('ctl00$MainContent$ClientInfoFormView$CancelBtn').click();
```

(make sure you're using actual button ID).  Sometimes using DOM methods works better.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, same effect, page freezes.  the formview's cancel buton is rendered as "<a id="MainContent_ClientInfoFormView_CancelBtn" class="btn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ClientInfoFormView$CancelBtn','')">Cancel</a>.  So i had to specify correct ID, but again, asyncpostback succeeded, and page freezes afterward.

Comment: Any luck solving this? Having similar problem.

Comment: @Hunter @chris Another thing to try is to place that code into setTimeout e.g. `setTimeout("$get('ctl00$MainContent$ClientInfoFormView$CancelBtn').click()",10);`